# Why does qdel comman return 'Unknown Job Id'

Tags: queue, torque, pbs, mom

**OS Version:**

CentOS release 4.6 (Final) Kernel \r on an \m 2.6.9-100.ELsmp

**Problem**

When I run qdel i get the following error:

```
qdel: Unknown Job Id 20432.scyld.localdomain
```

**Information**

Output of qstat -n:

> head0.localdomain: 
>                                                                      Req'd  Req'd   Elap Job ID               Username Queue    Jobname
>   SessID NDS   TSK Memory Time  S Time
>
> ---
>
> 20432.head0.localdom USERNAME standard pc-iw-1     32729     1 128    --  72:00 R 00:23    n39/5+n39/4+n39/3+n39/2+n39/1+n39/0

**Content of /var/spool/torque/server_name**'

scyld.localdomain

**Question**
Why do I get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but here is the answer for posterity:

The problem is that your `/etc/hosts` file has a different first hostname than your `server_name` file. Your `server_name` file has `scyld.localdomain`, and your `/etc/hosts` has your hostname as `head0.localdomain`. If you run `qdel 20432.head0.localdomain`, the command will work.

The solution is to change your /etc/hosts file, so that the first entry is:

```
127.0.0.1     scyld.localdomain
```

Everything after those characters is unimportant. If you also want the host to be known as head0.localdomain, you can just add that entry after scyld.localdomain on the same line.

I hope this helps someone out.